# how can i close a subprocess started by python program without closing the program

Tags: python, shell, unix, command-line, subprocess

I have a the following python program which open a command as subprocess and displays its output. This command though waits for user input after displaying information. I on the other hand want to get that information and close this subprocess and get back to what program is doing

Program is this

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from commands import *
import subprocess, os, sys, time

cmd = '/usr/local/bin/astrisctl reset'

p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
time.sleep( 5 )
p.kill()

out = p.stderr
if out == '' and p.poll() != None:
        print "No output from the commnand"
        sys.exit()
if out != '':
        sys.stdout.write(out)
        sys.stdout.flush()

print "i am back"
```

i want something like

```
something something
 0) xyz-0008E8
 1) xyz-000AB9
 2) xyz-000D18
 3) xyz-000D2B
 4) xyz-000E9D

pick a choice
i am back
```

but comes like

```
dta-rack-04:~ admin$ python Desktop/getBurnInLogs.py 
something something
 0) xyz-0008E8
 1) xyz-000AB9
 2) xyz-000D18
 3) xyz-000D2B
 4) xyz-000E9D
Choose a device: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Desktop/getBurnInLogs.py", line 16, in <module>
sys.stdout.write(out)
```

but i am hoping

```
something something
 0) xyz-0008E8
 1) xyz-000AB9
 2) xyz-000D18
 3) xyz-000D2B
 4) xyz-000E9D

pick a choice
i am back
```

Main purpose is to not wait for that choice.

Also if you could suggest a good way to get this options in list looking like {'xyz-000E9D', 'xyz-000E9D'..... etc etc}

Thanks a lot for your help and time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send it SIGKILL then use

```
p.kill()
```

This should kill the process immediately

If you want to wait for it to finish (which it doesn't sound like you do), then use

```
p.wait()
```

UPDATE: in the case that the output is coming from stdout and not stderr, you'll need to capture that.  Since you're doing some weird stuff, you'll want to make it unbuffered

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=0)
```

and then read from `p.stdout`, handle with care.

You can also get rid of `shell=True` pretty easily

```
cmd = ['/usr/local/bin/astrisctl', 'reset']
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=0)
```

Comment: i tried that didn't work... See the updated code. Is there any other way you meant?

Comment: made the change and removed it.. see the updated question please

Comment: perfect it works after removing sys.stdout.write(out).. i changed it to print. but i still see something like  <open file '<fdopen>', mode 'rb' at 0x1016fe780>. Any way to get rid of that?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the output you're seeing is actually coming from `stdout` and not `stderr`

Comment: thanks Ryan. it works. Can you please update your answer and i can accept it so that you can get your points.

Comment: @AjGauravdeep done, if you want to know which stream the output is going to you can always test it in the shell by throwing one away to `/dev/null`